# Prove that $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given $A$ is a $3$rd order Real Symmetric Matrix such that $A^6=I$ Then Prove that $A^2=I$

My try: Given that $A^6=I$ we have

$$A^6-I=(A^2-I)(A^4+A^2+I)=0$$

Now our aim to prove $A^4+A^2+I$ is an invertible matrix

Also $$A^4+A^2+I=(A^2-A+I)(A^2+A+I)$$

So to prove both $A^2-A+I$ and $A^2+A+I$  both are invertible

Can i have any clue?

Comment: Real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues.

Comment: Also, what is a "3rd order matrix"? Does that mean it is 3 by 3?

Comment: yes 3 by 3 square matrix

Comment: In title you wrote "Prove $A^2=I$". In question you wrote " Prove $A^4=I$". In your attempt you are proving something else. Be specific, what you actually want?

Comment: yes sir i edited thank you

Comment: @CaptainLama, not sure for the OP, but we used to say _the n-th order determinant_. We didn't say the same for matrices probably because matrices can be rectangular, not just square ones.